# How can I create multiple transitions in a ZStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create multiple transitions inside a ZStack.

This is a test view with some text and a circle which both have their own transition.

```
struct Test: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State private var showCircle: Bool = false
    @State private var showRect: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
             if showRect {
                 VStack {
                     Text("Hello World")
                         .foregroundColor(.white)
                         .padding()
                 }
                 .background(Color.green)
                 .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }

            if showCircle {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.purple)
                    .transition(.slide)
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            withAnimation {
                self.showRect.toggle()
                self.showCircle.toggle()
            }
        }
        .onDisappear() {
            withAnimation {
                self.showCircle.toggle()
                self.showRect.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I add this view like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var toggler: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            if toggler {
                Test(isPresented: $toggler)
            }

            Button("Show/Hide") {
                withAnimation {
                    self.toggler.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The transitions work onAppear. 
But onDisappear seems to get called during the removal and not before.


How can I reset the state vars to trigger the transitions on removal or what other approach should I use?

Other attempts: 
I also tried creating custom modifiers to use them with Anytransition.modifier - but failed because I couldn't typecast to access the State vars and Anytransition.modifier requires the modifiers to conform to ViewModifier.


dismiss function inside the TestView which works if I want to dismiss the view from itself but obviously doesn't when it's dismissed by its parent.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this, instead of onAppear/disappear

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var isButtonVisible = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $isButtonVisible.animation()) {
                Text("Show/Hide button")
            }

            if isButtonVisible {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Hidden Button")
                }.transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or with button

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var isButtonVisible = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.isButtonVisible.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Press me")
            }

            if isButtonVisible {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Hidden Button")
                }.transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you also can combine transition: check this out: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/06/26/animations-in-swiftui/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! From my understanding this code animates in such a way only because SwiftUI accommodates the newly present Button.  I'm trying to do something different. I want to have two different transitions on two nested views. How can I do this?